# How to approximate $0.714286$ as a fraction of $\pi$?

Tags: rational-numbers, pi

I'm doing an exercise that tells me that the answer must be a *multiple of pi*, like $12\pi$ or $\dfrac23\pi$.

I need to approximate $0.714286$ as a fraction of $\pi$.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What do you get when you divide by $\pi$?

Comment: 0.714286 / pi = 0.22737..
Still the fraction of this number does not meet the right answer for the exercise.

Comment: well, then you have $0.714286 =  0.22737 \pi$

Comment: Already tried to insert 0.22737π, but it continues to say that it must be simplified to multiple of π.

Comment: This has nothing to do with $\pi$, but the number coincides with $\frac{5}{7}$ to the given number of decimal places.

Comment: The decimal number $0.714286$ is close to $5/7$ but this is not intrinsically about $\pi $.  Of course multiplying by $22/5$ will give the common approximation.

Comment: Perhaps the real question you should ask yourself is: is $0.714286$ the correct answer? It looks very strange to me when the question demands an answer in multiple of $\pi$ but the answer you have doesn't look like a simple fraction multiplied by $\pi$.

Comment: [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) is a tool for such things: enter a number and it will try to guess its analytic form. Its best guess for your number is $5/7$, however,

Answer (score 4):

You may compute the continued fraction for $\frac{\pi}{C}$ where $C$ is your constant:
$$ \frac{\pi}{C}=[4;2,1,1,21,1,35,\ldots] $$
and by expanding $[4,2,1,1]=\frac{22}{5}$ we get:
$$ C = 0.714286 \approx \frac{5\pi}{22}.$$
A better approximation is given by expanding $[4,2,1,1,21,1]=\frac{497}{113}$, so
$$ C = 0.714286 \approx \frac{113\pi}{497}.$$

Comment: Or, since $C \approx \dfrac57$ and $\pi \approx \dfrac{355}{113}$, we have $C \approx \dfrac57 \dfrac{\pi}{\frac{355}{113}} = \dfrac{113\pi}{497}$.